# Disable a linux sound card

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, sound-card

I have updated to Kubuntu 12.10 from 12.04 and my sound stopped working ... I think because of I have two soundcards in my system and I think that disabling one of them shouldsolve the problem. Here is the output of inxi:

```
$ inxi -Ax
Audio:     Card-1: NVIDIA GF106 High Definition Audio Controller
             driver: snd_hda_intel     bus-ID: 05:00.1
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) 
             driver:     snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:14.2
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: 1.0.25
$
```

I want to disable the NVIDIA GF106 because it's HDMI output is not coming to my earphones. How do I do that? Or any other tips to get the sound back?
Thanks a lot.

Here is the `aplay -l` output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Headset [Logitech USB Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and here is the `~/.asoundrc`

```
pcm.!default {type hw card 0 device 0}
ctl.!default {type hw card 0 device 0}
```

and still not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your NVIDIA card is set as the default audio device; I have a similar issue when trying to get audio via HDMI in e.g. Flash. Problem is my Realtek card is set as default and some applications doesn't let you select which sound device to use.
I solve the issue by setting my HDMI audio as default aduio device, which can be achieved by editing the `.asoundrc` file in your home directory.

Here's what to do. First you have to find the proper card and device you want to use. Run the command `aplay -l`.
I'm guessing you want audio to come out your USB headphones? From the output of `aplay -l` you can see that the USB headphones is **card number 2** and **device number 0**, so put the following in your `.asoundrc` file.

```
pcm.!default {
type hw
card 2
device 0
}

ctl.!default {
type hw
card 2
device 0
}
```

Comment: modified the question to include my output of `aplay -l`

Comment: Even after applying the changes it is not working :(

Comment: I'm guessing you want audio to come out your USB headset? (correct me if I'm wrong). From `aplay -l` you can see that the **card number** is **2** and **device number** is **0**, so your `.aoundrc` should read `pcm.!default { type hw card 2 device 0 }` and `ctl.!default { type hw card 2 device 0 }`. And remeber to restart any application that you want to use the new default device.

Comment: I've found it helpfull to have several `.aoundrc.*` files in my home dir. E.g. I have a file called `.aoundrc.hdmi` file so that I can just do a `cp ~/.asoundrc.hdmi ~/.asoundrc` whenever I want to set HDMI as the default device.

Comment: I've edited my answer according to the information supplied from `aplay -l`.

Comment: No, actually I want the output from the analog device of the ATI SB. The USB headphone is plugged into a Windows Virtual machine and it works there. So, for me card 0, and device 0 were the obvious changes... That's how I created the .asoundrc

Comment: Have adjusted the mixer levels with `alsamixer`? There's usually a separate channel for headphones/AUX output, you should also make sure that it is not muted.

Comment: Strangely I cannot start alsamixer: `$ alsamixer
cannot open mixer: Invalid argument`

Answer (score 4):

1. You can knock PCI/PCIe cards out from under ALSA with the `remove` sysfs node:

   ```
   echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/sound/card0/device/remove
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   # current cards
   $ cat /proc/asound/cards
   0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                       HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfcba0000 irq 73
   1 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                       HD-Audio Generic at 0xfca00000 irq 76
   2 [Mic            ]: USB-Audio - Samson Meteor Mic
                       Samson Technologies Samson Meteor Mic at usb-0000:09:00.3-2.3, full speed
   3 [SoundBar       ]: USB-Audio - Dell AC511 USB SoundBar
                       Dell Dell AC511 USB SoundBar at usb-0000:09:00.3-2.4.1, full speed

   # remove cards
   $ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/sound/card0/device/remove
   1
   $ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/sound/card1/device/remove
   1

   # updated cards
   $ cat /proc/asound/cards
   2 [Mic            ]: USB-Audio - Samson Meteor Mic
                       Samson Technologies Samson Meteor Mic at usb-0000:09:00.3-2.3, full speed
   3 [SoundBar       ]: USB-Audio - Dell AC511 USB SoundBar
                       Dell Dell AC511 USB SoundBar at usb-0000:09:00.3-2.4.1, full speed
   ```

   To re-enable the card(s) poke the PCI `rescan` node:

   ```
   echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan
   ```
2. USB cards are a little trickier since you have to read the USB device path out of the `/sys/class/sound/cardX/device` symlink to [plumb it into `device/unbind`](https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/):

   ```
   CARD=card3; \
   basename $(readlink /sys/class/sound/$CARD/device) | \
   sudo tee /sys/class/sound/$CARD/device/unbind
   ```

---

Note that removing card 0 will confuse `alsamixer`:

```
$ alsamixer
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

...so make sure to select a different card with the `--card` option.

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly, your system would have PulseAudio. To disable an audio device, install [PulseAudio Volume Control](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/pavucontrol/) and use the 'Configuration' tab to disable devices.